# Login Wordpress user automatically on REST API call

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a react application and currently the user authentication done with Wordpress. So I'm using [JWT_AUTH](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)! plugin to manage user login functionality.
So now the requirement has changed and the users should be able to login to both React and the Wordpress websites with one single login attempt. This means if the user login to the React application, he should automatically log in to his Wordpress application as well. Also if the user login on Wordpress application he should automatically log into his react application as well.

I have created a custom REST API endpoint to do this requirement. But it's not working as expected. This endpoint is working when I using this API link with a browser. That because it doesn't have the ability to store cookies with the REST API call. 
I also tried to generate auth cookies with the rest API call but it gave me the "500" error.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'user/v1', '/api-login-check', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'rest_api_login_user',
        'schema' => array(
            'type' => 'array'
        )
    ));
});

function rest_api_login_user($object, $request = null) {

    $response = array();
    $parameters = $request->get_json_params();

    $creds = array();

    $creds['user_login'] = $object['username'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $object['password'];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ($user) {
        $response['code'] = 200;
        $response['message'] = __("User logged in", "wp-rest-user");

        return new WP_REST_Response($response, 123);
    }else{
        $response['code'] = 403;
        $response['message'] = __("User not logged in", "wp-rest-user");
    }

}
```

Is there any easy way to do this? Also if there a way to redirect user to different url from a rest api call, that also fine.

Comment: "It's not working as expected" is a little vague. Please expand on your question. Are you able to login to your React application but not visa versa?

Comment: @Jamie_D Sorry for confusing you. What I wanted to do is if a user login with my React application, he should automatically login to the Wordpress application. Also, if a user login to my Wordpress application he should log in to the React application automatically as well. It means the login should work in both ways.  <br/>
So this is what I meant.